# PowerBI: Multiply total with %share in another table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a measure that calculates the total for a certain account number among numerous accounts:  Total EUR `Account1 = CALCULATE('GL '[Total EUR], Account[Account number]="1")` and then put in a table to show cost per financial quarter:

Table 1

[image: img_t1]

Also; an example of source data:

Source data

[image: img_source_data]

Now, this sum per quarter I want to split into four different categories based on another table:

Table 2

[image: img_t2]

So I want to get the below table where the % share per Category and FQ has been multiplied by the total for the applicable FQ.
I do not have the categories in the source data for the main table (Table 1)

Table 3

[image: img_t3]

Comment: Please show your table structure of your source with soem data in it so we can help you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply, much appreciated! I have update the post with a picture of the source table; so it is a table with many accounts, but I want to sum only the account 7210 and then split that sum based on info in my Table 2

Comment: So how does table 2 look and how is it related to table1?

Comment: Table 2 looks like the link to Table 2, can you see it?. It is currently not linked to Table 1 which I believe is a problem. Simply put, e.g if the sum in Table 1 is 100, and in Table to it says that the share for Category A=90% and B=10%, then I want to get a table that says: A=90, B=10.

Comment: If I then add on some complexity saying that in Period 1 e.g. January, the sum in Table 1 is 100, the Category split is A=90% and B=10% and in Period 2 e.g. Feb, the sum in Table 2 is 200 and the split is A=40% and B=60%, then I want it to be: Jan: A=90, B=10. Feb A=80, B=120. In theory it is easy, but I do not really know how to achieve it in PowerBI...

Comment: But what is the link column? Please read a bit on relations and how they work so you understand my question better.

Comment: Hi Aldert, I have figured this out by another help source, not link needed!

Comment: Please close the question.